# handleSubmit is does not called in formik with reactnative?

Tags: react-native, formik

**Problem:**

I have created a react native application. There I am using Formik. My code looks like this.

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    // fineId: "",
    licenceNo: "",
    location: "",
    vehicleNo: "",
    vehicle: "",
    driverDetails: "",
    // offenceId: ""
  }}
  validationSchema={Yup.object({
    licenceNo: Yup.string().required("LicenceNo Required!"),
    vehicleNo: Yup.string().required("VehicleNo Required!"),
    vehicle: Yup.string().required("Vehicle Required!"),
    driverDetails: Yup.string().required(
      "DriverDetails Required!"
    ),
    // offenceId: Yup.string().required("OffenceId Required!"),
  })}
  onSubmit={(values, formikActions) => {
    this._onPress(values);
    setTimeout(() => {
      formikActions.setSubmitting(false);
    }, 500);
  }}
>
  {props => (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.FormGroup}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={this.state.fineId}
          placeholder="FineId"
          placeholderTextColor="#9b9b9b"
          autoFocus
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          editable={false}
          selectTextOnFocus={false}
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.FormGroup}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={props.values.licenceNo}
          onBlur={props.handleBlur("licenceNo")}
          placeholder="Driver Licence No"
          placeholderTextColor="#9b9b9b"
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          selectTextOnFocus={false}
          onChangeText={props.handleChange("licenceNo")}
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.vehicleInput.focus();
          }}
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
      {props.touched.licenceNo && props.errors.licenceNo ? (
        <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
          <Text>{props.errors.licenceNo}</Text>
        </View>
      ) : null}
      <View style={styles.FormGroup}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Location"
          placeholderTextColor="#9b9b9b"
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          selectTextOnFocus={false}
          editable={true}
          value={props.values.location}
          onChangeText={props.handleChange("location")}
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          marginLeft: "10%",
          marginRight: "10%",
          marginBottom: "5%"
        }}
      >
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          initialRegion={this.state.focusedLocation}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          zoomControlEnabled={true}
          style={styles.map}
          onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
          ref={ref => (this.map = ref)}
        >
          {marker}
        </MapView>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.FormGroup}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Vehicle"
          value={props.values.vehicle}
          placeholderTextColor="#9b9b9b"
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          selectTextOnFocus={false}
          onChangeText={props.handleChange("vehicle")}
          onBlur={props.handleBlur("vehicle")}
          ref={el => (this.vehicleInput = el)}
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
      {props.touched.vehicle && props.errors.vehicle ? (
        <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
          <Text>{props.errors.vehicle}</Text>
        </View>
      ) : null}
      <View style={styles.FormGroup}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Driver Details"
          value={props.values.driverDetails}
          placeholderTextColor="#9b9b9b"
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          selectTextOnFocus={false}
          multiline={true}
          numberOfLines={4}
          onChangeText={props.handleChange("driverDetails")}
          onBlur={props.handleBlur("driverDetails")}
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
      {props.touched.driverDetails &&
        props.errors.driverDetails ? (
          <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
            <Text>{props.errors.driverDetails}</Text>
          </View>
        ) : null}


      <Button title="Do Fine" type="submit" onPress={() => (props.handleSubmit)}></Button>

    </View>
  )}
</Formik>
```

The problem that I facing is when I try to press the submit button it does not call the function. I tried a lot to find a solution to this problem. But I was not able to do so. Can someone help me to overcome this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not calling the `handleSubmit` function.

```
<Button title="Do Fine" type="submit" onPress={() => props.handleSubmit} />
```

In this part of your code you are defining your button's `onPress` as a function returning another function. Doing this the button will not call the handleSubmit from formik but will return it inside the button. You can either directly place the `handleSubmit` function inside the onPress

```
onPress={props.handleSubmit}
```

or call it after the callback:

```
onPress={() => props.handleSubmit()}
```

Comment: What is different between them? `onPress={propa.handleSubmit} and onPress={()=>props.handleSubmit()}`

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: there is a difference. but both will execute the function. the difference is the arrow function version will get re-created every render, and is less performant.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
onPress={handleSubmit(submit)}
```

in your button.
And then give the handleSubmit props by putting

```
const { handleSubmit } = props
```

in your form.
Finally just add

```
const submit = values => {
  console.log('submitting form', values)
}
```

outside of your form.